# getAttribute isPermaLink is returning null for element in rss feed with Protractor

Tags: javascript, xml, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I tried many ways to get value of the attribute isPermaLink using protractor.

I can get the value of any other element fine, but isPermaLink always returns null..

**HTML**

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">public-anger-grows-over-coronavirus-123829864.html</guid>
```

**Code**

```
const isPerma = element(by.xpath('//guid[@isPermaLink]')).
console.log('isPermaLink value ', await isPerma.getAttribute('isPermaLink'));
```

If I try other elements like source tag I can get the value

```
<source url="http://www.ap.org/">Associated Press</source>
```

**Element located in dev tools**
[image: DevTools Screenshot]

**Link to Yahoo Rss feed being used:** https://news.yahoo.com/rss/

Comment: Are you sure you are `//rss/channel/item/guid[@isPermaLink]` this is working correctly?

Comment: Sry, I updated the locator for that example.

Comment: You are aware that element.all will return an array of element object instead of a single object?  If there is only one matching object you should just use `element()`. Also you appear to be capitalizing letters which are not present in the actual HTML. Try `//guid[@ispermalink]`

Comment: Sorry disregard my comment about HTML case being incorrect, I can see your locator seems correct. Not sure how I misread that

Comment: sry again, updated the element.all to element, but it will return same thing.

Comment: Does it find the element itself? Use `console.log(await element(by.xpath('//guid[@isPermaLink]')).getText())` and see if the tag text is logged

Comment: It returns nothing, just an empty string.

Comment: If I wrote $x('//guid[@isPermaLink]'); in the chrome browser console it will return the guid itself, I can return outerHTML, innerHTML and textContent using getAttribute.

Comment: Strange, are you sure this is the only applicable element? When you do it in browser console does it find multiple elements?

Comment: [Imgur](https://imgur.com/y6V1vZN)

Comment: [Imgur](https://imgur.com/dURIQyS)

Comment: I have uploaded two images that have what in guid after exec $x('//guid[@isPermaLink]');

Comment: This is what you need to be checking https://imgur.com/a/d0bFvkA

Comment: Yes, it is, but your isPerma is in lowercase.

Comment: [Imgur](https://imgur.com/fxnjxrt)

Comment: I would make sure that it is finding the element. Note that in your screenshot you have 50 matching elements but your functionality should still work from what I see. put `browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedCondtions.visibilityOf(element(by.xpath('//guid[@isPermaLink]'', 15*1000, 'Element not found within 15 seconds)`

Comment: Still returns null..

Comment: Also I used both getAttribute('isPermaLink'); and getAttribute('ispermalink'); in case it's should lower case, and both return null but if I get for example url of source tag it's return the value easily...

Comment: by the way, you can check the values here in yahoo rss feeds. [link] https://news.yahoo.com/rss/

Comment: There must be something obvious I am missing on this question and it is confusing me. I'm going to make an edit

Comment: it's not HTML, so you need to parse the XML portion using page source and an xml parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers (or rather my understanding of the problem):

1. How you can get the attribute?

```
let $permaLink = $$('guid[isPermaLink]').get(0);
let attr = await browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].getAttribute("isPermaLink")', $permaLink.getWebElement());
console.log(attr) // false
```

2. Why `await element.getAttribute('isPermaLink')` doesn't work?

Imagine you have an `iframe` inside an html page, and you're looking for an element inside of this frame. In this case you can interact with the element in the browser's console (locate it etc), but from protractor side you'll only be able to interact with it after `browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.tagName('iframe')).getWebElement());`

In your case, you have an xml inside of html page, which behaves similarly. However, protractor only works with the document itself (not the document inside the document). The problem is if you try `switchTo` you'll get an error `no such frame: element is not a frame`. Because the method is designed to ONLY work with iframes, but the concept is the same

Comment: @DublinDev  just FYI

Comment: is there anyway other than using browser.executeScript?

Comment: the options I see here: 1. look up on the internet if there is an existing module to work with xml. 2. try look under the hood of protractor and see if you can tweak `switchTo` and make it work with xml. 3. this xml is being parsed to html and displayed on the page. You can work with that html instead. But given the the complexity of all of these options I personally would still stick to `executeScript`